# Add results from second query to answer from first query

Tags: javascript, dexie

I have the problem that at least one of the then() functions is not waiting for the one before to end.

The code is shortened but roughly like this:

```
        var objCheck = {};

    var id = thisClick.attr('id');
    APP.db.checkInfo.get(id).then(function (resultDetail) {
        objCheck.details = resultDetail;
    }).then(function () {
        var checkPoints = APP.db.checkRooms.where('check_id').equals(id);
        checkPoints.toArray(function(dataArray) {
            dataArray.measures = [];
            objCheck.checkpoints = dataArray;
        });
    }).then(function () {
        var arrayLength = objCheck.checkpoints.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            var roomId = objCheck.checkpoints[i].room_id;
           var measure = APP.db.measures.where('room_id').equals(roomId);
           measure.toArray(function(dataArray) {
            objCheck.checkpoints[i].measures = dataArray;
        });
        }
    }).then(function () {
        $.ajax(
         // Here I send then objCheck to the server
       ).done(...);
    }).catch(function(error) {
     alert ("Error upload: " + error);
    });
```

If I print out the objCheck to the console at the end I see that measures is filled in. But in the ajax() call it is not sent along. So it looks to me like the last then() runs before the second last one finished.

It seems like a misunderstanding from my side. Can somebody tell me what is wrong in my logic?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @Liam Thanks. I didn't know about this. I thought because my question is specific to a library it would make sense to narrow it down in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return something (promise or just object, array, ...) in the callback of each then:

```
var objCheck = {};

var id = thisClick.attr('id');

APP.db.checkInfo.get(id).then(function (resultDetail) {
    objCheck.details = resultDetail;
    return objCheck;
}).then(function () {
    var checkPoints = APP.db.checkRooms.where('check_id').equals(id);
    return checkPoints.toArray();
}).then(function (dataArray) {
    dataArray.measures = [];
    objCheck.checkpoints = dataArray;
    var arrayLength = objCheck.checkpoints.length;

    var promises = objCheck.checkpoints.map(function(chk) {
        var roomId = chk.room_id;
        return APP.db.measures.where('room_id').equals(roomId);
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(function(res) {
    objCheck.checkpoints.forEach(function(chekpoint, i) {
        chekpoint.measures = res[i];
    });
    return objCheck
}).then(function () {
    $.ajax(
        // Here I send then objCheck to the server
    ).done(...);
}).catch(function(error) {
    alert ("Error upload: " + error);
});
```

Comment: I see now that I need to learn a lot more about Promises. There is a bug in your code. In the line "chekpoint.measures = res[i];" the element res[i] is a Promise object and not the data I need. I try to get this resolved now. Thank you so far.